# return looped switch conditional nested with jsx?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, openweathermap

I'm using a weather API and managed to get everything how I wanted. However, the api comes with boring and bland icons that I want replaced with my own animated weather icons. I decided to replace the weather icons with the custom animated weather icons instead. However, I'm stuck on figuring out how to return the custom icons in my return statement.

Here is my code I have a lot of it so I'll only be showing the relevant sections.

```js
                    const weatherData = async () => {
                        // Get forecast 5 days etc..
                        const weatherResponse1 = fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${data.city},${data.country_code}&appid=&units=imperial`)
                        
                        const [response1] = await Promise.all([weatherResponse1]);

                        const weatherJson1 = await response1.json();

                        let newForecast = []
                        let weathericonState = []

                        for (let i = 0; i < weatherJson1.list.length; i+=8){
                            switch (weatherJson1.list[i].weather[0].icon){
                                // clear night or few clouds day or night time or night mist
                                case '01n':
                                case '03n':
                                case '03d':
                                case '04n':
                                case '50n':
                                weathericonState = ( 
                                    <div class="icon cloudy">
                                        <div class="cloud"></div>
                                        <div class="cloud"></div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                                break;
                                // clear day time or day mist
                                case '01d':
                                case '50d':
                                weathericonState = (
                                    <div class="icon sunny">
                                        <div class="sun">
                                            <div class="rays"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                                break;   
                                // broken clouds day time
                                case '04d':
                                weathericonState = (
                                    <div class="icon sun-shower">
                                        <div class="cloud"></div>
                                        <div class="cloud"></div>
                                        <div class="sun">
                                            <div class="rays"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                                break;                                                     
                            }

                            newForecast.push(weatherJson1.list[i])
                        }
                    
                        this.setState({
                            weatherData: newForecast,
                        })
                    }

                    const weatherResults = weatherData();

                    weatherResults;

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**Return statement:**

```js
            return (
            <div className="container-fluid" id="userfluidprofile">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-7">
                            {
                                this.state.weatherData.map((row, index) => 
                                    <div className="weatherContainer" key={index}>
                                        // I want to replace this img with my custom animated icons returned from my nested looped conditional.
                                        <img src={'https://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + row.weather[0].icon + '.png'} alt="Weather Icon" />
                                    </div>
                                )
                            }   
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
```

Comment: Can you include a smaller code snippet? Remove the parts that aren't relevant to your problem. That should make the code easier to read and thus increase your chances of getting a reply. Also maybe fix your indentations?

Comment: sure thing let me reduce some of the repetitive sections.

Comment: Okay I reduced all the code that was irrelevant to my problem and only included the portion relevant to my problem.